# LaTeX Error: File `scan1' not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex, external-files, includegraphics

Currently, I am trying to generate a LaTeX document with the R package `tinytex`. The file the package tries to compile looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{/var/folders/w2/myfolder/}

\begin{document}

This is the summary for: Jane Doe.

\includegraphics{scan1}

\end{document}
```

The file itself is located in the directory `/var/folders/w2/myfolder/`. Moreover, a function call to `list.files('/var/folders/w2/myfolder/')` gives

```
[1] "Exam-2021-07-14.tex" "scan1.png"           "scan2.png"
```

Particularly, the file `scan1.png` is contained in the same directory. Unfortunately, `tinytex` keeps throwing the error

> ! LaTeX Error: File `scan1' not
> found.

I already tried removing the line `\graphicspath{...}` and included the file extension `.png` in `\includegraphics{...}`. How can I troubleshoot this problem further?

`tinytex` gives me also  the information

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled.

before the compilation process.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please try with `\graphicspath{./var/folders/w2/myfolder/}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi I just tested this and get the same error. Just to be clear: Both files (the .tex as well as the .png) are located in `/var/folders/w2/myfolder/`.

Comment: Try an extra set of braces: `\graphicspath{{/var/folders/w2/myfolder/}}`

Comment: As already mentioned the argument for graphicspath need to be a list in the form of `{path}{path}{...}` note the braces on each. It will loop over each of there tokens. In your example it sees the separate tokens `/ v a r /... ` and tries each one by one. IIRK each path should end with a `/`